# Get previous consecutive 10 rows sale to get sum

Tags: sql-server

I have a table t1

```
**id**        **Date**             **Sales**
102         20180101                    50
102         20180102                    60
102         20180103                    70
102         20180104                    90
102         20180105                    10
102         20180105                   100
102         20180106                   100
102         20180107                    30
102         20180108                    20
102         20180109                    34
102         20180110                    40
102         20180111                    50
102         20180112                    60
```

Now I want the previous10 records for each row like for 20180111 sum of sale should be 464 which is the sum of the previous 10 records sale and for 20180112 it should be 474.

Comment: There are plenty of examples out there if you do a quick google search. What have you tried so far? Include that in your question.

Comment: Doom awaits you if multiple rows can have the same id and date values. Without a set of columns to guarantee an order, there is no such thing as "previous" or "next".

Comment: You don't need to include tagged keywords in the title as its redundant.

Comment: @lgor I did try but it was providing me all consecutive rows sum.

Comment: I think it is covered in great detail in this question on dba.se: [Date range rolling sum using window functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/114403/57105)

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov I don't have permission to create index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you think the following is what you need ?

```
WITH temp
AS (SELECT id,
           date,
           SUM(sales) AS n_Sale
    FROM dbo.t
    GROUP BY id,
             date)
SELECT *,
       SUM(t.n_Sale) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC ROWS 9 PRECEDING)
FROM temp AS t;
```

Comment: There might be multiple hotels on a same date.

Comment: in this case if i don't have consecutive 10 days I want to put 0 on that column rather than calculating previous 10 and if I have hotel 102 with having 10 consecutive values then the entry should be on 11th row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add a consecutive index and then group by truncate(index/N), and get the sum of values.

for instance, to get the sum every 3 elements (mysql):

```
SELECT truncate((row_number-1)/3,0) grp, sum(sales) total 
FROM (
  SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 as row_number, 
  sales
  FROM (
    SELECT 452 as sales UNION ALL
    SELECT 324 as sales UNION ALL
    SELECT 342 as sales UNION ALL
    SELECT 342 as sales UNION ALL
    SELECT 342 as sales UNION ALL
    SELECT 232 as sales
  ) as t1, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t2) as tf group by grp;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3149e4/524

Comment: The data is not static.The number of rows are in thousand so for every hotel w.r.t date I need to create a column which will generate the values on it's 11th row by using previous 10 row sales and same for 12th row